# Vue 3 search component: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, vue.js, vuejs3

I have like this component for searching in my app:

```
<template>
    <div class="search">
        <input
            type="text"
            @input="search($event.target.value.trim())"
        />
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    data: Array,
    metro: Object,
})
const emit = defineEmits(['onSearch'])
const metro = ref({})
const query = ref("")

const filterByMetro = () => {
  if (metro.value.id) {
    var data = props.data
    if(query.value) {
      data = search(query.value)
    }
    const result = data.filter(item => metro.value.metro == 1 ? item.district.id == metro.value.id : item.district.isMetro == false)
    emit('onSearch', result)
    return result
  }
}
const search = (val) => {
    var data = props.data
    if(metro.value.id) {
        data = filterByMetro()
    }
    if (val !== '' && data && data.length > 0) {
        const rx = new RegExp("^" + val, "im")
        const rxm = new RegExp('(?<= )[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z][а-яА-Яa-zA-Z ]*(?=,| )', 'giu')
        const result = data.map(item => [(rx.test(item.address.match(rxm)?.[0] || null) ? 1 : 0) ||
            (rx.test(item.district.map(d => d.title).join("\n")) ? 2 : 0), item
        ])
            .filter(([k, v]) => k)
            .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
            .map(([k, v]) => v);
        emit('onSearch', result, val)
        query.value = val
        return result
    } else {
        emit('onSearch', data)
        return data
    }
}

watch(() => props.metro, (val, old) => {
    metro.value = val
    if(val.id) {
    // Filter by metro
        filterByMetro()
    } else {
        // Reset metro
        search(query.value)
    }
});


</script>
```

I use component like this:

```
<Searchbar
  :data="list"
  @onSearch="setResult"
  :metro="currentMetro" // ref
/>
```

How I can change logic here to avoid `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error in my case?

Comment: I suspect that your watch is watching something, and that the callback triggers the watch back, hence creates an infinite loop somehow.

Comment: I gave all the code as an example on the body of the question. Where do you think it might be? @kissu

Comment: It is necessary to somehow think up and implement the filtering logic with several parameters correctly